# What's the most efficient way to process a large text file line by line

Tags: java

I (think) I'm processing a text file line by line until I find a specific token;

```
(Psuedo Code)

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("myTextFile.txt");
while (scanner.hasNext() {
    boolean found = process(scanner.nextLine();
    if (found) return;
}
```

Some of the files are huge. Does this code actually scan the file line by line or does either the Scanner or FileReader read the entire file into memory and then work it's way through the memory buffer line by line?

Comment: can you try BufferedReader?

Comment: It's line by line.
I'm not sure what constitutes found, but be careful your match isn't split across two lines.  You may also get better performance reading in blocks of bytes rather than in lines (again, depends slightly on what you're looking for).

Comment: It depends on what you need. If you are using a Java Standalone for batch processing, it's just a matter of time and proper object management and you will be fine with the BufferedReader... You will only use the memory needed by each line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
boolean found = false;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("Your string"))
       found = true;
}
```

Comment: +1 - this should be the preferred way to do it. If you don't need `line` and `found` outside of the loop, move their declarations inside (`for(String line; (line = br.readLine) != null;) { /* loop body */ }`) - then you don't pollute outer scope with variables that are unused there.

Answer (score 1):

You want [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C:\\testing.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

            while (dis.available() != 0) {
                System.out.println(dis.readLine());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
                bis.close();
                dis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

[source](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedinputstream-example/)

Comment: `BufferedReader` works fine regardless whether the file fits into memory or not. Also, the difference between `BufferedReader` and `BufferedInputStream`, apart from the obvious, is that the input stream accesses raw bytes, while a reader reads characters.

Comment: @Puce I didn't write the code, if you look at the end of my post it is a direct copy paste to illustrate how the code works.

Comment: `DataInputStream.readLine()` is deprecated (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()), this essentially leaves us with `BufferedReader` being the only good option (apart from writing your own) to do this well. Input streams are designed for raw data (byte) access, nothing else. Besides, `BufferedReader` probably uses input streams under the hood anyway, adding character conversion to it. It's the best bet overall.

Comment: @amn again I did not write this code.  Feel free to message the author.

Comment: There are very few correct uses of available(), and this isn't one of them. It's not a test for end of file. Feel free to contact the author yourself. You took the responsibility of posting it, you get to attract the upvotes, and the downvotes. -1

Answer (score 0):

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("myTextFile.txt");
boolean found = false;
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath, CharSet.forName(<char-set-name>)){
   for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
     found = process(line);
     if (found){
        break;
     };
   }
}
```